# Graphing directional user assignments

Tags: c#, audit, change-tracking

I have a DB table which records changes made to orders. One of the properties on the order object is the ID of the administrator. When an administrator goes out-of-office they have the option of assigning a replacement; the replacement can then assign someone to replace themselves, who can then assign a replacement...

Each time a replacement is assigned the order is updated and an audit trail is created in a DB table named `audit_log`.

When an administrator returns to work they can remove their replacement, which should then cause their orders to be reassigned to them. This seems a simple problem but I'm having trouble with the logic behind deciding which orders should be reassigned. For example, take a look at the image below...

[image]

Now look what happens if `Admin 1` returns...

[image]

...so far so good, but if `Admin 2` *then* returns...

[image]

...`Admin 2` would be mistakenly reassigning an order from `Admin 1` because the audit log shows that `Admin 2` had previously reassigned it to `Admin 3` prior to leaving the office. But that order *shouldn't* be reassigned from `Admin 1` to `Admin 2` - it belongs to `Admin 1` and `Admin 1` is not out-of-office.

Consider the scenario where the order gets reassigned through 5 different administrators, then `Admin 3` returns and reclaims the order from `Admin 5`; if `Admin 4` *then* returns they should not be assigned the order, but if `Admin 1` or `Admin 2` returns then they should reclaim the order from `Admin 3`.

What this needs is a way of graphing the changes in assignment, then detecting which orders have been assigned *ahead of* a user but not *behind* a user, where...

- *ahead of* = a user who is to the right of a context user in the above images (`Admin 3` being *ahead of* `Admin 2`)
- *behind* = a user who is to the left of a context user in above images (`Admin 1` being *behind* `Admin 2`)

...but I just don't know how to build this? Are there any well-known algorithms or patterns from building such a graph, and any pointers as to how to implement such in C#?

Some additional information: The records in the `audit_log` DB table also have `id` and `recorded` (DateTime2) fields, so they can be retrieved in chronological order.